# postgresql: change primary key

Tags: database, postgresql

Until now I had a column `account_name` as the primary key for my database.  I'd now like to use a hash of `account_name` as the primary key instead.

So as an interim measure, I added an `account_hash` column and gave it the UNIQUE constraint, so that both `account_name` and `account_hash` exist together.

I populated `account_hash` for all database entries, and am now actually using `account_hash` as the key for the database, and am no longer actively using `account_name` for anything.

But of course because `account_name` is the "official" primary key, and must be NOT NULL, for any new entries I have been populating both `account_name` and `account_hash` with the same hash.

It's all working fine like this, but now I'd like to clean up the database, to get rid of `account_name` entirely, and to make `account_hash` the primary key instead.

What is the best way of doing this?  It is a working database that is in use constantly, so any change needs to be at minimum disruption to the users.

Here is the `\d+` information relating to the relevant columns:

```
            Column             |          Type          |          Modifiers          | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 account_name                  | character varying(255) | not null                    | extended |              | 
 account_hash                  | character varying(256) |                             | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (account_name)
    "users_account_hash_256_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (account_hash)
Has OIDs: no
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

You can drop the current primary key with

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT users_pkey;
```

Make the account_hash required with

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER account_hash SET NOT NULL;
```

After that you can add a new primary key with

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX indexname;
```

You may have to drop the `users_account_hash_256_key` constraint first to not have a duplicate and depending on how the unique index was created, you may have to create the index again for this.

If the account_name column is not used anywhere, it can then be dropped with

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN account_name;
```

**Note** I would advise against this action. Hashes have collisions, so if you use them as primary keys, there may be a time when you cannot insert a value into the database because of that. Also performance is worse with varchar indexes than with integers (or a UUID, if a very large keyspace is needed), so if there is no specific reason for using hashes, I wouldn't do this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  As for using a hash as a primary key, I looked into this in some detail, and the consensus seems to be that for sha256, the chance of a collision is many orders of magnitude lower than the chance of the Earth being wiped out by an asteroid in the next second.  Not worth worrying about.  And account_name was the user email address, which I'm keen to avoid storing and using, hence using a hash of that instead.  Wasn't sure really what else I could use as a key.

Comment: @drmrbrewer Ok, then at least make the field char and not varchar since all hashes are the same length. Char(64) in this case I think

Comment: Good point re Char(64).  Will that make a significant difference in performance, or is it just better practice to fix things at the right length when they can be?

Comment: Char vs Varchar: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29_even_for_fixed-length_identifiers